# What happens if a process keeps creating threads?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

What happens if a process keeps creating threads especially when the number of threads exceeds the limit of the OS? What will Windows and Linux do?

Comment: You can easily test this by spawning threads in a loop. It'd be similar to a fork bomb, but with threads instead of processes.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/07/08/3261309.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the threads aren't doing any work (i.e. you don't start them), then on Windows you're subject to resource limitations as pointed out in the blog post that Hans linked. A Linux system, too, will have some limit on the number of threads it can create; after all, your computer doesn't have infinite virtual memory, so at some point the call to create a thread is going to fail.

If the threads are actually doing work, what usually happens is that the system starts thrashing. Each thread (including the program's main thread) gets a small timeslice (typically measured in tens of milliseconds), and then it gets swapped out for the next available thread. With so many threads, their working sets are large enough to occupy all available RAM, so every thread context switch requires that the currently running thread is written to virtual memory (disk), and the next available thread is read from disk. So the system spends more time doing thread context switches than it does actually running the threads.

The threads will continue to execute, but very very slowly, and eventually you will run out of virtual memory. However, it's likely that it would take an exceedingly long time to create that many threads. You would probably give up and shut the machine off.

Most often, a machine that's suffering from this type of thrashing acts exactly like a machine that's stuck in an infinite loop on all cores. Even pressing Control+Break (or similar) won't take effect immediately because the thread that's handling that signal has to be in memory and running in order to process it. And after the thread *does* respond to such a signal, it takes an exceedingly long time for it to terminate all of the threads and clean up virtual memory.